# php-ga Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, google-analytics

I'm trying to do server side Google Analytics tracking and came across php-ga.
For some reason this is throwing an error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /home/priedelc/public_html/refll/api_ga.php on line 85 - where 85 is the line with use UnitedPrototype\GoogleAnalytics;

Anyone got a hint for me? Thanks!

```
//load namespace
use UnitedPrototype\GoogleAnalytics;
//autoload import script
require_once 'autoload.php';

//initialze new tracker & session
$tracker = new GoogleAnalytics\Tracker('xxxx', 'xxxx');
$session = new GoogleAnalytics\Session();
//setup visitor
$visitor = new GoogleAnalytics\Visitor();
$visitor->setIpAddress($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDRESS']);
$visitor->setUserAgent($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

//page
$page = new GoogleAnalytics\Page('/page-name');
$page->setTitle('Page Title');
//track pageview
$tracker->trackPageView($page,$session,$visitor);

//event
$event = new GoogleAnalytics\Event();
$event->setCategory('Category');    //string, required
$event->setAction('Action');        //string, required
$event->setLabel('Label');          //string, not required
$event->setValue(1);                //integer, not required
$event->setNoninteraction('true');
//track event
$tracker->trackEvent($event,$session,$visitor);
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? I'm guessing 5.2 or below, before namespaces were introduced

Answer (score 1):

The line looks okay:

```
use UnitedPrototype\GoogleAnalytics;
```

Check your PHP version: http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

If your version is below 5.3.0, you need to upgrade your PHP if you'd like to use namespaces:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

Unfortunately I'm not able to test your code with a lower PHP version right now, but I guess it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Hmm yea, I use 5.2.17 - sadly I can't upgrade it.. shared host.. any workaround?

Comment: I asked Google for a workaround but unfortunately there isn't any. What about outsourcing the file to another server and request it or send data to it by a script on your shared host? It should work, if your mainfocus isn't on performance.

Comment: That's a great idea! Sadly it's the only server I can use for this.. Too bad :( Any other solution for server side GA tracking you know of?

Comment: @PaulRiedel check out http://piwik.org if you're not dependent to Google Analytics. I'm not sure but there could be an GA API for older servers.